# Exact algorithm that generated the aligned&cropped version of celebA dataset

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, face-recognition

On there site it says that they align and crop the face images roughly based on the two eyes' positions. But I can't seem to find how they did it exactly. Anybody has more information on that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be answered by anyone else but the dataset creators which even offer their help on their website.

Comment: @Piglet 1) Offering help on their site doesn't mean they can provide timely response to every message; 2) You can't figure out without contacting the creators doesn't mean nobody else can; 3) What I'm doing here "in gods name" is trying to confirm my findings with someone else who also reverse-engineered it.

Comment: @windancer I'm trying to do something similar. Mind sharing your findings?